# Finding the index of a blank line within a string

Tags: c#, string

Suppose I have a string that contains a text file, carriage returns and tabs and all. How do I find the index of the first blank line (to include lines-containing-only-whitespace) in that string?

**What I've tried:**

In this case, I have a working function that leverages a bunch of ugly code to find the index of the blank line. There must be a more elegant/readable way to do it than *this*.

To be clear, the below function returns the section from a string from a supplied 'title' to the index of the first blank line after the title. Supplied in full, since most of it is consumed by the search for that index, and to avoid any 'Why in the WORLD do you need the index of a blank line' questions. Also to counteract the XY Problem, if it's happening here.

The (apparently working, haven't tested all edge cases) code:

```
// Get subsection indicated by supplied title from supplied section
private static string GetSubSectionText(string section, string subSectionTitle)
    {
        int indexSubSectionBgn = section.IndexOf(subSectionTitle);
        if (indexSubSectionBgn == -1)
            return String.Empty;

        int indexSubSectionEnd = section.Length;

        // Find first blank line after found sub-section
        bool blankLineFound = false;
        int lineStartIndex = 0;
        int lineEndIndex = 0;
        do
        {
            string temp;
            lineEndIndex = section.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, lineStartIndex);

            if (lineEndIndex == -1)
                temp = section.Substring(lineStartIndex);
            else
                temp = section.Substring(lineStartIndex, (lineEndIndex - lineStartIndex));

            temp = temp.Trim();
            if (temp.Length == 0)
            {
                if (lineEndIndex == -1)
                    indexSubSectionEnd = section.Length;
                else
                    indexSubSectionEnd = lineEndIndex;

                blankLineFound = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lineStartIndex = lineEndIndex + 1;
            }
        } while (!blankLineFound && (lineEndIndex != -1));

        if (blankLineFound)
            return section.Substring(indexSubSectionBgn, indexSubSectionEnd);
        else
            return null;
}
```

FOLLOW-UP EDIT:

**The result (based heavily on Konstantin's answer)**:

```
// Get subsection indicated by supplied title from supplied section
private static string GetSubSectionText(string section, string subSectionTitle)
{
        string[] lines = section.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        int subsectStart = 0;
        int subsectEnd = lines.Length;

        // Find subsection start
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Trim() == subSectionTitle)
            {
                subsectStart = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Find subsection end (ie, first blank line)
        for (int i = subsectStart; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                subsectEnd = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines, subsectStart, subsectEnd - subsectStart);
```

}

The primary differences between the result and Konstantin's answer are due to framework version (I'm working with .NET 2.0, and it doesn't support string[].Take), and leveraging Environment.NewLine instead of the hardcoded '\n'. Much, much prettier and more readable than the original pass. Thanks all!

Comment: I'm suspecting the answer will be "Christopher, learn RegEx."

Comment: What is the function supposed to return?  From the question, it sounds like you want the index of the first character of the blank line, but the method looks like it returns the blank line itself.

Comment: I should have been more clear; I've edited the question to include the purpose of the function. In short, the subsectionTitle is searched for in the section, and a string is returned containing all text from the found subsectionTitle to the first blank line following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) :

```
string s = "safsadfd\r\ndfgfdg\r\n\r\ndfgfgg";
string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
int i;
for (i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lines[i]))     
    //if (lines[i].Length == 0)          //or maybe this suits better..
    //if (lines[i].Equals(string.Empty)) //or this
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",lines.Take(i)));
```

EDIT: responding the OP's edit.

Comment: +1: If you're working with lines of text, you should process it as such.

Comment: (Missed the edit-timer): This is much more sensible way of thinking about it. I will be editing the product into the question

Answer (score 3):

By "blank line", you mean a line that contains only whitespace? Yes, you should use regex; the syntax you're looking for is `@"(?<=\r?\n)[ \t]*(\r?\n|$)"`.

- `(?<=`…`)` indicates a lookahead, something that should precede what you're looking for.
- `\r?\n` indicates a newline, supporting both the Unix and Windows conventions.
- `(?<=\r?\n)` is therefore a lookahead for the preceding newline.
- `[ \t]*` means zero or more space or tab characters; these will match the content (if any) of your blank line.
- `(\r?\n|$)` means newline or end-of-file.

Example:

```
string source = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\n   \r\nLine 4\r\n";
Match firstBlankLineMatch = Regex.Match(source, @"(?<=\r?\n)[ \t]*(\r?\n|$)");
int firstBlankLineIndex = 
    firstBlankLineMatch.Success ? firstBlankLineMatch.Index : -1;
```

Comment: There should probably also be a long comment following the regex to help the poor fellow who has to come along and maintain it 6 months down the line.

Comment: Yes, a line that contains only whitespace. Tabs, spaces and carriage returns.

This answer looks way more elegant than what I wrote! My only concern with regex is that it's not very readable (though way better than mine).

Comment: @ChristopherBerman: Fair point; many developers are not proficiently familiar with regex.

Comment: @PeteBaughman Indeed. I just add comment lines with links to this question, this answer, and with the explanation in this question.

Comment: Do apple pc's still use \r as end-of-line? Then this answer cannot be made to work on both windows, unix/linux, and apple text files.Other than that this regex solution is superior to using Split().

Comment: @Roland: `\r` hasn't been used in a long time. It was already considered a relic in 2012: https://superuser.com/a/439443

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:  It seems like you're OK with re-allocating strings once per line.  It would be possible then, to write an iterator that would lazily evaluate the string and return each line.  For example:

```
IEnumerable<string> BreakIntoLines(string theWholeThing)
{
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        endIndex = theWholeThing.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine,startIndex) + Environment.NewLine.Count; //Remember to pick up the newline character(s) too!
        if(endIndex = -1) //Didn't find a newline
        {
            //Return the end part of the string and finish
            yield return theWholeThing.SubString(startIndex);
            yield break;
        }
        else //Found a newline
        {
            //Return where we're at up to the newline
            yield return theWholeThing.SubString(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
            startIndex = endIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

You could then wrap that iterator in another one that only returns the lines you care about and discards the others.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetSubsectionLines(string theWholeThing, string subsectionTitle)
{
    bool foundSubsectionTitle = false;
    foreach(var line in BreakIntoLines(theWholeThing))
    {
        if(line.Contains(subSectionTitle))
        {
            foundSubsectionTitle = true; //Start capturing
        }

        if(foundSubsectionTitle)
        {
            yield return line;
        } //Implicit "else" - Just discard the line if we haven't found the subsection title yet

        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            //This will stop iterating after returning the empty line, if there is one
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this method (along with some of the others posted) do not do EXACTLY what your original code does.  For example, if the text in subsectionTitle happens to span a line, it won't get found.  We'll assume that the spec is written in such a way that this isn't allowed.  This code will also make a copy of every line that gets returned which the original code did too, so that's probably OK.

The only benefit of doing it this way vs string.split, is that when you're done returning the SubSection, the rest of the string doesn't get evaluated.  For most reasonably sized string you probably don't care.  Any "performance gains" are likely to be non-existent.  If you really cared about performance, you wouldn't be copying each line in the first place!

The other thing that you get (that actually could be valuable) is code re-use.  If you're writing a program that parses documents, it's probably helpful to be able to operate on individual lines.

Comment: Awesome. While performance is a non-concern for me in this particular application (overshadowed entirely by file I/O), this is useful to see. I'm reading up on lazy evaluation and iterators now. Thanks Pete!